# fitting model with training data isnt working

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, file-not-found, model-fitting

So, I tried to train my deep learning model with the whole dataset, and I get this error.

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-1d451569b986> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 full_model.fit(x = full_data, epochs = NUM_EPOCHS, callbacks = [ full_model_tensorboard, full_model_early_stopping])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) NOT_FOUND:  /content/drive/MyDrive/Dog images/dog-breeds-model/train/db7d4420a51a8928e82bcb1d9a6c4167.jpg; No such file or directory
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[Shape/_6]]
  (1) NOT_FOUND:  /content/drive/MyDrive/Dog images/dog-breeds-model/train/db7d4420a51a8928e82bcb1d9a6c4167.jpg; No such file or directory
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_53213]
```

I tried to fit the model, and I was expecting it to run, but it didn't.

I have no idea what this error means. I'm new to machine learning. Can someone explain what might be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your file path is wrong, check your image path and make sure it is correct, there should be no space (` `) in the path

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess from how you phrased your question that the training worked on a small dataset but failed when you tried doing it on the whole training data ?

It's written in your traceback that there are 2 files that don't exist.

Comment: Yes, it worked on a small dataset the first time